# android google analytics v3: "Service unavailable"

Tags: android, google-analytics

following the simple guide here,
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/

when i run my app, i get this,

```
10-28 18:01:17.973  27022-27069/com.foo.bar W/GAV3﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Service unavailable (code=1), will retry.
10-28 18:01:17.973  27022-27069/com.foo.bar I/GAV3﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
10-28 18:01:17.973      525-865/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START cmp=com.google.android.gms/.analytics.service.AnalyticsService (has extras) } U=0: not found
```

from the debug, it's trying to start a service that doesn't exist. it seems like i should have to define that in my manifest, but the guide says nothing about that.

i've placed `analytics.xml` in my res/values folder as such,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources
    xmlns:tools="https://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">

  <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXX-1</string>
  <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
  <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
  <integer name="ga_dispatchPeriod">1</integer>
  <bool name="ga_debug">true</bool>
</resources>
```

i'm completely stumped here since the guide is so simple. if it makes any difference (and it shouldn't), i'm building with android studio / gradle, and adding the dependency like this,

```
compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
```

EDIT: had a thought ... this device DOES NOT run google services. does the google analytics lib depend on the google service APK being installed?

Comment: Yes, you have to include the GA SDK in the mobile app. You also have to change the UA-XXX-1 to your GA UA ID. That property ID has to belong to a mobile app property.

Comment: Similar problem here. A slightly different angle, as I'm following this guide: https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/testing-play-campaigns. I've added the jar to the export libs, but still get I/GAV3(21698): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Campaign found [GOOD!]: utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_term=testTerm&utm_content=testContent&utm_campaign=testCampaign, [then BAD]:
 W/ActivityManager(376): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START cmp=com.google.android.gms/.analytics.service.AnalyticsService (has extras) }

Comment: Possibly related: https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=294

Comment: @AlisonS yes, i included the lib. yes, i just masked my ID for public consumption.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can ignore that warning for now.

From the Google Mobile App Analytics group:

```
The SDK is simply attempting to connect to a global dispatch service, which is unavailable on your device.  The hits are still being generated and sent to GA normally.
```

The GA developer site will provide more information on this soon.

Link to the group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ga-mobile-app-analytics

Answer (score 1):

If you are using analytics V3 you should remove

```
    <bool name="ga_debug">true</bool>
```

as ga_debug is for v2

refer:[Google Analytics SDK for Android - EasyTracker Parameters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/parameters)

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, you might have just forgotten to initialize your tracker.

Under "next steps" on the [GA3 site](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/advanced), it states "Before any data can be measured, you must initialize at least one tracker via GoogleAnalytics singleton by providing a Context and a Google Analytics property ID:"

Just insert this code into your main activities' onCreate method:

```
// Initialize a tracker using a Google Analytics property ID.
GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).getTracker("UA-XXXX-Y")
```

You'd think they'd mention this on their main page, but I guess they just kind of expect you'll be curious about the advanced settings.

Comment: don't think this is the issue. it *is* logging data. i believe the system obtains the tracker ID and initializes based on the `analytics.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the

```
GAServiceManager.getInstance().setLocalDispatchPeriod(10);
```

after this line it seems to work just fine and send the events