# Google Analytics V3 for Android: Service unavailable (code=1), using local store

Tags: android, google-analytics

I've implemented GAv3 in my app for Android as it described in official tutorial. I'm getting the following warnings in logcat:

```
W/GAV3    ( 3031): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Service unavailable (code=1), will retry.
I/GAV3    ( 3031): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
W/GAV3    ( 3031): Thread[Service Reconnect,5,main]: Service unavailable (code=1), using local store.
```

There is high-speed internet access, tracking id is set properly.
And I see no statistics for my devices. Tested on Android 2.3 and 4.3.1.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19660444 for a little bit more detailed answer about this issue.

Answer (score 7):

I get this error message as well in my app, but Google Analytics works fine, I can see all the expected statistics from my app.

I haven't been able to figure out what the message means, but at least that is not the reason why you don't get any data in Google Analytics.

One thing to keep in mind, is that you don't really see anything useful in Google Analytics untill the day after the events happen. This makes it quite difficult to debug errors.

Comment: Is it really 24 hours later that we receive the informations? Because I have the exact same error messages, but 22h passed now since I added the Google Analytics library and threre is still 0 session logged.

Comment: It can take up to 24 hours, according to Google:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009219?hl=en

But as I said in the above comment, I don't think this error message is the reason for your data not showing up in Google Analytics. Perhaps you can create a separate post with your Google Analytics code, and we can see if there's something missing there?

Comment: My sessions just showed up after the weekend. It is really not convenient for testing purpose to have to wait that long...

Comment: Actually the delay shouldn't be more than half an hour or so. Also note the tip from **[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13226356/56285)**: "An interesting thing I've noticed which may also help, **Google Analytics web interface doesn't show data from the current day by default**. [...] you need to select the current day".

Comment: @Jonik - god damned... :) I just wasted a couple of hours, fiddling with my tracker configuration!!